# I renamed my package in Eclipse but some errors/messages still come up under the old package name in LogCat. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse

I renamed my project a few days ago.  I renamed the package and updated all references, I updated the manifest to reflect the new name.  I've done a full project text search for the old project name and not a single instance is returned in my search.

Yet - when I run my project, some messages still get generated under the old project name.

In LogCat, it shows 3 items:

```
All Messages
com.old.old_proj_name (Session Filter)
com.new.new_proj_name (Session Filter)
```

Both filters get populated when I run my app.

I get errors like this sometimes:

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(com.old.old_proj_name/com.new.new_proj_name.class_name) : java.lang.NullPointerException`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Post your Manifest file. I bet there the refactoring went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file and modify the activities name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean (eclipse: Project->Clean..) and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  There was an old build installed on my test tablet with the old package name.  It seems Eclipse was somehow still listening in on that when I ran new builds.  I uninstalled the old build and the messages have disappeared.